# Unwanted horizontal scroll in WordPress site on page-scroll

Tags: html, wordpress

for some reason the wordpress site I am building ([plumeofficial.com](https://plumeofficial.com/)) always jumps to the right when I click the buttons that scroll down the page (best noticeable on the social-icons)

I cannot explain this beaviour but guess there is a bug in the HTML that I simply don't find. I reproduced this on Chrome and Firefox.